# cinnamon: get original look and feel using xsession

Tags: linux-mint, x11, cinnamon

OS: Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon

```
$ cat .xsession
xmessage -file /etc/motd
/usr/bin/cinnamon
```

1. why do not I get the same look and feel as i do get without the above .xsession file? it also affects a few things

   - when i open a gnome-terminal, i cannot see the input that is sent to terminal
   - log out button looks different and does not log out on click
2. how .xsession file work in conjunction with selecting a session from the login screen?

> - last session
> - run xclient script
> - cinnamon
> - cinnamon 2d
> - gnome classic
> - secure remote connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `~/.xsession` file has one line:

```
gnome-session --session=cinnamon
```

I'm running xrdp on the Linux Mint server and connecting with an RDC client.  It looks like I'm sitting at the desktop; even my conky script is running on the RDC client.